# Configure ALSA to use a specific mic and output

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm trying to configure ALSA to use my HDMI sound as output, and my USB mic as input. I have a working `asound.conf` without dmix/dsnoop:

```
pcm.usb_mic_raw {
  type hw
  card Device
  device 0
}

pcm.usb_mic_plug {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm usb_mic_raw
    format S16_LE
    rate 48000
    channels 1
  }
}

# Don't use pcm.hdmi because it's taken by the default config files
pcm.hdmi_raw {
  type hw
  card HDMI
  device 9
}

pcm.hdmi_plug {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm hdmi_raw
    format S16_LE
    rate 48000
    channels 2
  }
}

pcm.!default {
  type asym;
  playback.pcm "hdmi_plug";
  capture.pcm "usb_mic_plug";
}
```

This works fine, except that there's no mixing--only one program can play sound at a time.

When I then try to switch from `plug` to `dmix`, I get the following error:

```
juice:~ aplay -D hdmi_plug good.wav                                                                  1 :(
Playing WAVE 'good.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
[..works..]

juice:~ aplay -D hdmi_dmix good.wav                                                                  1 :(
Playing WAVE 'good.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available
```

The section I added is below:

```
pcm.hdmi_dmix {
  type dmix
  ipc_key 200
  slave {
    pcm hdmi_raw
    format S16_LE
    rate 48000
    period_time 0
    period_size 2048
    buffer_size 8192
    channels 2
  }
  bindings {
   0 0
   1 1
  }
}
```

If it matters, I'm on Arch Linux, and I have pulseaudio and pulseaudio-alsa installed.

Comment: Pulseaudio typically grabs all available ALSA devices. Does it make a difference if you stop or suspend Pulseaudio? Also, Pulseaudio offers an ALSA compatibility layers, so all applications use ALSA will go through Pulseaudio. What is your use case of using ALSA directly, if you already have Pulseaudio? Couldn't you solve this through the compatibility layer?

Comment: No, uninstalling both pulseaudio packages has no effect.

Comment: Use case: When I open Discord without pulseaudio installed, I see zero devices and have no audio. When I open up Discord with pulseaudio installed I see exactly one output device, called "alsa". I'm installing pulseaudio so I can use Discord. I'm configuring ALSA because pulseaudio doesn't seem to be detecting my devices, but its ALSA compatibility layer lets me configure them in ALSA.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> When I open Discord without pulseaudio installed, I see zero devices and have no audio.

That means Discord probably has no ALSA driver, only a Pulseaudio driver. (But Discord is closed source, so I can't say for sure).

> When I open up Discord with pulseaudio installed I see exactly one output device, called "alsa".

Not sure how Discord names Pulseaudio devices.

> I'm configuring ALSA because pulseaudio doesn't seem to be detecting my devices,

Then you need to debug this. What does `pactl list short` show? You should see at least one ALSA card (possible more) with associated sources and sinks.

If it does: Also install `pavucontrol`, start it while Discord is running, and select the right sources and sinks for Discord.

Comment: I did eventually get pulse working in Discord, but it looks like other things use ALSA by default and the devices are occupied, so I really still need to get ALSA working

Comment: So basically EITHER you use Pulseaudio on top of ALSA, let Pulseaudio grab all the ALSA devices and control them, including mixers, and let legacy ALSA applications use the ALSA compatibility layer to go through Pulseaudio (which works flawlessly, I never had an application where that didn't work), OR you ditch Pulseaudio and use ALSA-only. Any sort of "I want to use both ALSA directly AND Pulseaudio" will only cause headaches, and at least on my system, just doesn't work.

Comment: So if there are "other things that seem to use ALSA by default", try to figure out why the compatibility layer is not working for them (which starts with "move your custom  soundrc out of the way, and let Pulseaudio's soundrc take over, which defines the later as default device).